# about recipes package in R

Tags: r, r-recipes

Hi I am using recipes for feature engineering in machine learning models.
However, when I used step_dummy, dummy variables are regarded as numeric variables, not factor.
I think this might be problematic when we use random forest or other tree models.
How can we change this? PDP shows that dummy predictor is treated as numeric. so X-axis has 0.25, 0.5.......
This should have only 0 and 1 (since dummy).

```
library(modeldata)
library(recipes)
library(caret)
library(ranger)
library(ggplot2)
library(pdp)

data(okc)
okc <- okc[complete.cases(okc),]

rec <- recipe(~ diet + age + height, data = okc)

dummies <- rec %>% step_dummy(diet)
dummies <- prep(dummies, training = okc)

dummy_data <- bake(dummies, new_data = okc)
summary(dummy_data)
dummy_data<-na.omit(dummy_data )
dummy_data<-dummy_data[1:2000,]

dummy_data$diet_strictly.anything<-factor(dummy_data$diet_strictly.anything)%>% factor(labels = c("No", "Yes"))

myTrainingControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                                  number = 5, 
                                  savePredictions = TRUE, 
                                  classProbs = TRUE,
                                  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                                  verboseIter = F)

fit_rf <- caret::train(diet_strictly.anything ~ .,   
                       data =dummy_data, 
                       method = "ranger",
                       tuneLength = 2,     
                       importance = "permutation",
                       trControl = myTrainingControl)


# Define a prediction function wrapper which requires two arguments
predict.function <- function(object, newdata) {
        predict(object, newdata, type="prob")[,2] %>% as.vector()
}

plt_ICE <- pdp::partial(fit_rf, 
                        pred.var = "diet_mostly.vegetarian", 
                        pred.fun = predict.function, 
                        train = dummy_data) %>% autoplot(alpha = 0.1)
plt_ICE
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the `step_dummy` documentation:

> step_dummy creates a a specification of a recipe step that will convert nominal data (e.g. character or factors) into one or more numeric binary model terms for the levels of the original data.

The function appears to be working as expected in this case, by converting the categorical variable `diet` (stored as a `character` type in the `okc` data) into a set of binary numeric variables corresponding to the levels of `diet`.

If you're treating the variables as outcomes (i.e. trying to predict if someone has a specific type of diet), you're right that the dummy variables should not be encoded as numeric. If you're interested in changing the 'diet' dummies back to factors, a tidy approach might be:

```
library(tidyverse)
dummy_data <- dummy_data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('diet')), list(as.factor))
```

If you're using those dummy variables as predictors, tree-based modeling tools in `R` (I've primarily used `rpart`, `randomForest` and `ranger`) can handle dummy variables as **predictors** encoded as numeric, and the interpretation of variable importance measures would be the same as if the variables were encoded as 2-level factors or logical variables.

Comment: I deeply appreciate your help. However, a partial dependency plot shows that dummy variable is treated as a continuous variable. I editted and added more codes.

Comment: That's correct, numeric variables here will show up as continuous on a plot like the one you've called. However, because they only take two discrete values in your data (calling `unique()` on any of the dummy variables should return only values from the set `(0, 1)`) they're treated the same in tree-based models as two-level factors or logical variables.

Comment: Thank you for your comment !!!  So you mean we can ignore the predicted probability between 0 and 1 ??
If so, it does make sense. For example x-axis 0.5 has no meaning, right??

Comment: Ah, I may have misunderstood initially, thanks for clarification. Are you treating the dummy variables from `diet` as predictors or as outcomes? If you're using them only as predictors, then leaving as numeric is fine for the reasons of my first comment, but if you're treating them as outcomes, I'd recommend converting back to factors so that the models handle them the way you'd expect for categorical outcomes. I'll update my answer to clarify that point.

Comment: edited to clarify, let me know if that helps. in any case i think the code block to convert numeric to factor solves the problem :)

Comment: I am using the dummy variable as one of predictors. However, it is strange to show up continous x-axis. For example, diet_mostly.vegetarian only has predictied probability of diet_strictly.anything in only 0 and 1, but in this case, diet_mostly.vegetarian has 0-1 like 0.25, 0.5.

Comment: I'm seeing `lapply(dummy_data, unique)`, which displays all unique values by column, returns only `0 1` for all 'diet' columns. The lines in your plot don't represent the actual input data to your model. If you're seeing multiple values on your plot's axis, it is likely due to the graph being only lines, and not lines and points (which would only occur at 0 and 1).